# Do i need to apply htmlspecialchars / htmlentites on json array?

Tags: php, jquery, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I wanted to ask that in a php script of mine which I am accessing through an ajax request, I am returning json data ( converted from an array ) as such

```
 echo json_encode($row_array);
```

I get this data in jquery and display it in a form. Do i need to apply htmlspecialchars /  htmlentites before returning the data?

Is do then whats the correct way to do it? The following code gives me an error:

```
echo htmlentities(json_encode($row_array));
```

Thanking you
Imran

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just test it yourself? You could have been done by now...

Comment: @WesleyMurch, It's a valid question.  Even if he had tested it, it might have worked but still been problematic.

Comment: @Brad: "Valid" does not mean "good". This shows zero research effort. What do you mean "it might have worked but still been problematic"?

Comment: @WesleyMurch, You can create broken HTML and get away with it.  He might have output straight JSON data to HTML, and it might have been fine until the day the JSON data contains `<` and `>`, for example.

Comment: @Brad: Obviously that would be the type of thing to test... HTML characters.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, ... obvious to you and I, not him.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, Ok, now it's a bad question.  Imran, be much more specific when you say "the following code gives me an error".  The only way it could would be on the `json_encode()`.  What data are you passing to it?

Comment: @WesleyMurch, It's JSON-ENCODED, that **is a string**.

Answer (score 2):

Do not apply htmlentities in this way.  You should walk the array before json encoding it and escape each element, then json encode the array of safe-to-display values.  In your usage json is just a transport layer for the array.  You are not displaying the json array, just the element data. Don't escape transport layers--it could make the json string invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Context is important.

You don't need to escape the data at all on the server side if it's going into a form input's `value` if you are using jQuery's `val()` function to populate it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6TWv/1/

```
var data = '<strong>STRONG TEXT</strong>';

$('input').val(data); // output is escaped
$('p').text(data);    // output is escaped
$('p').html(data);   ​ // output is not escaped
```

In addition, if you *were* to escape the data, don't do it like this:

```
// escapes the entire json string, not good - quotes will be broken
echo htmlentities(json_encode($row_array));
```

You would have to escape each item of `$row_array` first before json encoding it, either with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) after the array is built, or as you're building the array.

In general, you should prefer `htmlspecialchars` over `htmlentities`, but it's not likely you need either one.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a problem with single quotes in a JSON array.  Chrome doesn't like single quotes in a JSON response returned via ajax.  I escaped each value with htmlspecialchars(, ENT_QUOTES).

```
$theoptions['MemberList'] = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $memberelement = array(
                       'Display'=> htmlspecialchars($row['FullName'], ENT_QUOTES),
                       'Value'      =>  $row['ID']);
   $theoptions['MemberList'][] = $memberelement;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($theoptions);
```